# SpaCy: Do I need to perform early stopping while training the model for custom entities?

Tags: nlp, spacy, opennlp

I have divided my data into training and testing.

https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner

As per the code snippet given by spacy for training the custom entities, it seems like there is no early stopping. So I have a question here??

Should I write a custom code which performs the following set of things after every iteration:
1. Iteration completed.
2. Check the model accuracy on the testing data.
3. If the accuracy is more than the previous model then save it else continue.
4. Perform the next iteration.

Or I the final model after completing all the iteration for example 30 iteration is the best model??

Sample output of my custom code:
[image]

As per the above output is it right to say the best model is at iteration no 13?

Answer (score 2):

You should switch to the train CLI, which includes better evaluation metrics and early stopping: https://spacy.io/api/cli#train

`spacy convert` can convert a lot of common NER formats to spacy's internal training format and `spacy train` has a lot more options than the simple example training script. (spacy uses `spacy train` internally for the models it distributes.)